# NoClassDefFoundError even though Jar is present in classpath

Tags: java, jdbc, impala

I'm having a weird issue, I am trying to load the class `com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver` using Class.forName("com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver") but it's throwing exception during runtime. Can someone correct me on what wrong I'm doing here?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver
```

Printing the classpath using the following snippet does print the Jar present in the classpath.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"))
```

Comment: Please provide the full exception stacktrace. It will likely show the reason the class could not be initialized.

Comment: I'd also make sure that you're using compatible JDK. I think JDBC driver 4.1 should work with 7 and 8.

Answer (score 1):

The error message "Could not initialize class" likely means that the class was found, but threw an exception during initialization, perhaps in a static block.

This results in the ClassLoader not being able to "find" the class. Confusing, I know. See if there are any static blocks in this class, and if so, set a debugger breakpoint there to see what's going on.